# Laravel auth check for all pages

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I have created the Authentication, and its working perfectly. But there is some problem in checking the inner pages. For example,

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth' , 'do'=> function(){
return View::make('home.index');
}));
```

The index page is only visible for logged in users. But whenever I have go to the inner pages, for example `example.com/products`. The products page can be visible without log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if user is logged in in your views.
Or restrict all controller (if you use it)
Or check Route Groups, and give a filter to whole group of routes: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#groups

Comment: yeah, I can do that. the problem is I have lot of inner pages. Can't check all pages. There should be a simple solution

Comment: Route Groups are ideal for applying filters to achieve this, but I wouldn't suggest doing it at view level as a viable alternative - it doesn't kick in early enough (i.e. a `POST` could still have an effect before you start rendering a view that then kicks the user out)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution.

```
/**
 * Groups of routes that needs authentication to access.
 */
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() 
{
    Route::get('user/logout', array(
        'uses' => 'UserController@doLogout',
    ));

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('dashboard',  array(
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@showIndex',
    ));

    // More Routes

});

// Here Routes that don't need Auth.
```

Comment: Simple but effective, no?

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways of applying filters for many routes.

Putting rotues into `Route::group()` or if you using controllers add the filter there, add it in the `Base_Controller` so it will be applied to all. You can also use filter patterns and use a regex which applies the filter to all except a few you don't want to.

**Documentation**

Route filters: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Example to the pattern filter, as the others are basicly in the docs. This one could be the fastest but also the most problematic because of the problematic way of registering a regex in this function (the `*` is actually converted into `(.*)`).

```php
Route::filter('pattern: ^(?!login)*', 'auth');
```

This will apply auth to any route except `example.com/login`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
    Route::get('list', 'EventsController@index');     
});
```

Read more on the documentation page:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way but I take a whitelist approach.  Everything is blocked from public except for what the pages I put in this array.

```
 // config/application.php   
 return array(

    'safe' => array(
        '/',
        'card/form_confirm',
        'record/form_create',
        'card/form_viewer',
        'user/login',
        'user/quick_login',
        'user/register',
        'info/how_it_works',
        'info/pricing',
        'info/faq',
        'info/our_story',
        'invite/accept',
        'user/terms',
        'user/privacy',
        'email/send_email_queue',
        'user/manual_login',
        'checkin/',
        'checkin/activate',
        'system/list',
    ),

// routes.php
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    // Maintenance mode
    if(0) return Response::error( '503' );

    /*
        Secures parts of the application
        from public viewing.
    */
    $location = URI::segment(1) . '/' . URI::segment(2);
    if(Auth::guest() && !in_array( $location, Config::get('application.safe')))
        return Redirect::to( 'user/login' );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this code working fine with me

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The same problem can be solved using a BaseController to extends all Controller have must logged user.

Example:

```
class SomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index() { return view('some.index');}
}
```

just add a `__construct()` method to BaseController

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/myIndex'; // Redirect after successfull login

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth'); // force all controllers extending this to pass auth
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#protecting-routes)

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::filter('pattern: /*', array('name' => 'auth', function()
{
  return View::make('home.index');
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me . take a look at it.

```
Route::when('*', 'auth.basic');

Route::get('api/getactorinfo/{actorname}', array('uses' =>'ActorController@getActorInfo'));
Route::get('api/getmovieinfo/{moviename}', array('uses' =>'MovieController@getMovieInfo'));
Route::put('api/addactor/{actorname}', array('uses' =>'ActorController@putActor'));
Route::put('api/addmovie/{moviename}/{movieyear}', array('uses' =>'MovieController@putMovie'));
Route::delete('api/deleteactor/{id}', array('uses' =>'ActorController@deleteActor'));
Route::delete('api/deletemovie/{id}', array('uses' =>'MovieController@deleteMovie'));
```