# Check the user's auth in all controllers' actions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.3 and I have the following problem.

[UPDATE]

My initial trouble was the appearance of an error when performing actions on the site when the user was not logged in the system.

This happened when the browser is started, where cached information is displayed by default on the page. Site interface displayed for logged users, and in his system was not. At the same time, producing some action, I get an error that the user is not authorized.

I also have group auth middleware for all my routes. When I reboot page of the site, the middleware is activated and redirectedme to the login page. The main problem is the browser shows the cached information.

So, in addition to middleware for routes I decided to make auth check in controllers.

[/UPDATE]

I want to check user's auth in every controller's action. Making the auth check in every controllers' action manually isn't a solution, because there are many controllers and actions.

So I decided to make it globally.

As all controllers extends Main Controller (App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php), I decided write the 
auth()->check() in constructor:

```
function __construct()
{
    if(auth()->check()) dd('success');
}
```

But... nothing happened((( Then I found the callAction method in BaseController which Main Controller extends and made checking here:

```
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    if(auth()->check()) dd('success');
    return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
}
```

This time everything's OK, but I don't like this solution, because editing the core files isn't good.

Finally, I redeclared callAction method in Main Controller with auth checking, but I don't like this way too.

Is any solution?

Comment: What about using middleware?

Comment: I tried this way, but it didn't work for me( Nothing happened.

Comment: Just follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745897/laravel-auth-check-for-all-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware):

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile']);
```

Or:

```
Route::get('profile', 'UserController@show')->middleware('auth');
```

Or using [middleware groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-groups):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    // Controllers here.
});
```

Or using [controller's construct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: I have more than 50 routes including ajax-requests. It's not a solution to rewrite every route...

Comment: @PaulBasenko use [middleware groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-groups) for that. That is the third option in my answer.

Comment: As for group route, I've already used it. As I said, I need auth check in controller's action, not in routes.

Comment: @PaulBasenko you're reinventing the wheel here. Middleware were created to solve exactly this kind of a problem. If you want to build maintainable app, middleware is the right way to go.

Comment: my initial problem was the appearance of an error when performing actions on the site when the user was not logged in the system. This happened when the browser is started, where cached information is displayed by default on the page. Site interface displayed for logged users, and in his system was not. At the same time, producing some action, I get an error that the user is not authorized. Therefore, in addition to middleware for routes I decided to make auth check in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a group of routes this would be the easiest way

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
    // here all of the routes that requires auth to be checked like this
    Route::resource('user','UsersController');
}
```

another ways

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

another way is specified on controller routes

```
Route::get('profile', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
]);
```

see documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auth` middleware in your controller

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication