# Laravel Authenticating A User With Conditions

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a question to [Authenticating A User With Conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication) part in Laravel documentation.

In which controller and method should I insert this condition to make it work across the application. I didn't quite catch it.
Is it constructor of `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController` ?

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1]))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Apply a routes group in your routes, [like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18946619/3585500). You could then have public routes outside the group if you need that later.

Comment: Laravel login controller use AuthenticatesUsers trait, in which u can find its implementation.
Have a Look at this vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

Answer (score 1):

It depends which version you're using.  You linked to a 5.0 doc, so I'm not sure if you're actually using that.

In recent versions, you can either override the entire LoginController::login method or you can drill down to just the LoginController::attemptLogin method.  Both of which are actually defined in the AuthenticateUsers trait.

---

I tend to handle this differently. If a user is inactive or suspended, I like to display a different message to them than just a generic failed login. I'd prefer to use a middleware to check their status and redirect them with message about their account.

```
class CheckActiveMiddleware 
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check that the user is still active
        if($request->user()->active)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Your account has been deactivated.');
    }
}
```

This also allows you to deactivate users that are still logged in.  Since with your method, a logged in user that selected 'Remember Me' would still be able to use the application until they log out since your check is only on the log in.